# How can i pass a color to my UI if my property is a string in my database (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Right now i am getting a random hexadecimal color value and i am trying to assign it to a BackGroundColor. ( Yes it works if i hardcore a color)

The value is stored ( you can see in the below picture) but somehow it doesn't display the color and i am not sure why.

I have a feeling that it's because i am trying to give BackGroundColor a string so it doesn't recognize it since it's not a Color. But in a databse u can't put a Color property.

Any idea or other way to do it ? Thanks

[image]

**Line color value in the database**

```
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TasksGroupDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime TasksGroupDate { get; set; }

    public double ExpositionResult { get; set; }

    public string LineColor { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Tasks> Taches { get; set; }
```

**BaseViewModel.cs property**

```
private string lineColor;
public string LineColor
{
    get
    {
        return lineColor;
    }
    set
    {
        lineColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**TasksGroupPageViewModel.cs where i have my function generating the color and calling it in the constructor**

```
public string RandomColorGenerator()
{

    var random = new Random();
    var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
    return color;
}

    public TasksGroupPageViewModel()
    {

        DeleteTasksGroupCommand = new Command(new Action<object>((obj) =>
        {

            DeleteTasksGroup((TasksGroup)obj);
        }));

        LineColor = RandomColorGenerator();
        GetTaskgroups();

    }
```

**Edit for question in comments**

[image]

Comment: Is the `Binding Context` set to your `TasksGroupPageViewModel` instance?

Comment: use ToHex() and FromHex() to convert between Color and string

Comment: @SushiHangover yes every other things of my database works in the page

Comment: @Jason i am not sure where u want me to use this ? Thanks

Comment: I'm just pointing out that there is an easy way to convert between the two types.  You can use `Color` in your VM and convert to string when you save/load.

Comment: without seeing more code I can't say

Comment: @Jason ok i guess i'll have to find why, i'll still mark this answer as the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ToHex` and `FromHex` to convert `Color` to `string`

```
private string lineColor;
public Color LineColor
{
    get
    {
        return Color.FromHex(lineColor);
    }
    set
    {
        lineColor = value.ToHex();
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and

```
public Color RandomColorGenerator()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
    return Color.FromHex(color);
}
```

Comment: i wanna test this but i am not sure to what i should change my RandomColorGenerator() to since now if i do this : LineColor = RandomColorGenerator(); it says that i can't convert a string to color any idea ?

Comment: yes, have RandomColorGenerator() return a Color instead of a string

Comment: Thanks for answer, i edited my post, you can see that the data is there in LineColor but still doesn't appear any idea ? Thanks

Comment: does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  Are you doing your updates on the UI thread?

Comment: Well every other TasksGroup properties show up so idk why this one isn't and i am not sure what you mean by updates on the UI thread. I assign LineColor in the ViewModel constructor like i did above.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundColor` is a `Color` type object, convert your database hex string or random hex to `Color`

```
private string lineColor;
public Color LineColor
{
    get
    {
        return Color.FromHex(lineColor);
    }
    set
    {
        lineColor = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `RandomColorGenerator` method to the `BaseViewModel.cs`, set the `lineColor` in the BaseViewModel's constructor.

```
   public class BaseViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public BaseViewModel()
        {
            lineColor = RandomColorGenerator();
        }
        private string lineColor;
        public Color LineColor
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.FromHex(lineColor);
            }
            set
            {
                lineColor = value.ToHex();
                OnPropertyChanged("LineColor");
            }
        }

        public string RandomColorGenerator()
        {

            var random = new Random();
            var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
            return color;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```